# Making the syntax for random part of a mixed-model in lme4 shorter

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I was wondering if there might be a more concise way to write the syntax for the random part of the syntax as indicated below?

**PS.:** Essentially, I'm trying to get 2 uncorrelated set of random slopes for each level of my binary predictor `lb_wght` (*see correlation matrix of random-effects below*).

```
library(lme4)

math <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/mlgrp1.csv')
math <- within(math, lb_wght <- as.factor(lb_wght))

m <- lmer(
    math ~ 0 + lb_wght + lb_wght:grade + 
    (0 + dummy(lb_wght, "0") + dummy(lb_wght, "0"):grade|id) +  # This line and
    (0 + dummy(lb_wght, "1") + dummy(lb_wght, "1"):grade|id) ,  # This line
    data = math)
```

[image]

Comment: for those less familiar with lme4 could you give a verbal description of what this random-effects specification is doing?

Comment: @rnorouzian As I've commented on your other questions, you really need to explain the structure of your data better. `lb_wght` is already the numeric representation of a dummy-coded binary variable, so all those calls to `dummy` are adding a lot of unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to answer this question because I suspect the underlying statistical model is problematic, but this is the programming arm of StackExchange, so here's the programming solution:

Important points:

- A binary categorical variable represented as 0 and 1 is already dummy coded. It's certainly not problematic and at times useful to tell R that it's representing a categorical contrast via `factor`, but R will just turn that back into 0s and 1s before fitting that model.
- 0 and 1 can also be interpreted as boolean values. We can swap boolean values via negation.
- Using `dummy(lb_wght, "0")` is just providing a reversed encoding of the original binary variable. Likewise, `dummy(lb_wght, "1")` is essentially a no-op  -- it just gives you back the original dummy-contrasted variable.
- We can express the reversed encoding of `dummy(lb_wght, "0")` as boolean negation.

## data wrangling warm up

```
> library("lme4")
> 
> math <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/mlgrp1.csv')
> # A two-level contrast represented as dummy coding means we have 0 and 1
> # This is the same as FALSE and TRUE and so we can swap them using boolean negation
> math <- within(math, {
+                         lb_wght0 <- as.numeric(!lb_wght) 
+                         lb_wght1 <- lb_wght
+                      })
> head(math) # check what those new vars look like
    id female lb_wght anti_k1 math grade occ age men spring anti nb_wght lb_wght1 lb_wght0
1  201      1       0       0   38     1   2 111   0      1    0       1        0        1
2  201      1       0       0   55     3   3 135   1      1    0       1        0        1
3  303      1       0       1   26     0   2 121   0      1    2       1        0        1
4  303      1       0       1   33     3   3 145   0      1    2       1        0        1
5 2702      0       0       0   56     0   2 100   .      1    0       1        0        1
6 2702      0       0       0   58     2   3 125   .      1    2       1        0        1
```

## no correlation in the RE

```
> m <- lmer(
+   math ~ 0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade  + lb_wght1 +  lb_wght1:grade + 
+     (0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade  + lb_wght1 +  lb_wght1:grade || id),   # This line and
+   data = math)
> summary(m)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: math ~ 0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade + lb_wght1 + lb_wght1:grade +  
    ((0 + lb_wght0 | id) + (0 + lb_wght1 | id) + (0 + lb_wght0:grade |          id) + (0 + grade:lb_wght1 | id))
   Data: math

REML criterion at convergence: 15932

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.06601 -0.52971 -0.00312  0.53661  2.54121 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name           Variance Std.Dev.
 id       lb_wght0       61.9312  7.8696  
 id.1     lb_wght1       84.7006  9.2033  
 id.2     lb_wght0:grade  0.7044  0.8393  
 id.3     grade:lb_wght1  0.6598  0.8123  
 Residual                36.3585  6.0298  
Number of obs: 2221, groups:  id, 932

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
lb_wght0       35.48689    0.36619   96.91
lb_wght1       32.81813    1.35307   24.25
lb_wght0:grade  4.29283    0.09059   47.39
grade:lb_wght1  4.86449    0.32029   15.19

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            lb_wg0 lb_wg1 lb_w0:
lb_wght1     0.000              
lb_wght0:gr -0.533  0.000       
grd:lb_wgh1  0.000 -0.489  0.000
```

## matching the correlation structure in the OP

```
> m <- lmer(
+   math ~ 0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade  + lb_wght1 +  lb_wght1:grade + 
+     (0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade | id) + 
+     (0 + lb_wght1 +  lb_wght1:grade | id),
+   data = math)
> summary(m)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: math ~ 0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade + lb_wght1 + lb_wght1:grade +  
    (0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade | id) + (0 + lb_wght1 + lb_wght1:grade |      id)
   Data: math

REML criterion at convergence: 15931.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.09189 -0.52867 -0.00063  0.53419  2.54169 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name           Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 id       lb_wght0       61.1969  7.8228        
          lb_wght0:grade  0.6711  0.8192   0.04 
 id.1     lb_wght1       97.4494  9.8716        
          lb_wght1:grade  1.4314  1.1964   -0.35
 Residual                36.2755  6.0229        
Number of obs: 2221, groups:  id, 932

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
lb_wght0        35.4848     0.3646   97.31
lb_wght1        32.8506     1.4214   23.11
lb_wght0:grade   4.2930     0.0902   47.60
grade:lb_wght1   4.8827     0.3414   14.30

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            lb_wg0 lb_wg1 lb_w0:
lb_wght1     0.000              
lb_wght0:gr -0.527  0.000       
grd:lb_wgh1  0.000 -0.567  0.000
```

## for comparison, the OP's model:

```
> math <- within(math, lb_wght <- as.factor(lb_wght))
> m <- lmer(
+   math ~ 0 + lb_wght + lb_wght:grade + 
+     (0 + dummy(lb_wght, "0") + dummy(lb_wght, "0"):grade|id) +  # This line and
+     (0 + dummy(lb_wght, "1") + dummy(lb_wght, "1"):grade|id) ,  # This line
+   data = math)
> summary(m)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: math ~ 0 + lb_wght + lb_wght:grade + (0 + dummy(lb_wght, "0") +  
    dummy(lb_wght, "0"):grade | id) + (0 + dummy(lb_wght, "1") +      dummy(lb_wght, "1"):grade | id)
   Data: math

REML criterion at convergence: 15931.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.09189 -0.52867 -0.00063  0.53419  2.54169 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name                      Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 id       dummy(lb_wght, "0")       61.1969  7.8228        
          dummy(lb_wght, "0"):grade  0.6711  0.8192   0.04 
 id.1     dummy(lb_wght, "1")       97.4494  9.8716        
          dummy(lb_wght, "1"):grade  1.4314  1.1964   -0.35
 Residual                           36.2755  6.0229        
Number of obs: 2221, groups:  id, 932

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
lb_wght0        35.4848     0.3646   97.31
lb_wght1        32.8506     1.4214   23.11
lb_wght0:grade   4.2930     0.0902   47.60
lb_wght1:grade   4.8827     0.3414   14.30

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            lb_wg0 lb_wg1 lb_w0:
lb_wght1     0.000              
lb_wght0:gr -0.527  0.000       
lb_wght1:gr  0.000 -0.567  0.000
```

**edit: 2021-02-08 20:57 UTC**

**NB** This is not the question as asked, but instead what was demanded in a post-hoc comment. Nonetheless, the programmatic generation of indicator variables and a formula using base R is perhaps interesting. This could be rewritten to use `apply` .... but that seems like premature optimization for the problem at hand. I don't think it's a good idea to generalize this approach to more than two levels without really thinking about what that model would even mean, but again, *this is an answer to the programming question, not an endorsement of the statistical procedure it implements*.

## do an arbitrary number of levels in the experimental variable

This will automatically generate all the indicator variables and the formula.

```
> # GOOD LUCK WITH THIS
> library("lme4")
> 
> math <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/mlgrp1.csv')
> grps <- unique(math$lb_wght)
> 
> form <- "math ~ 0"
> 
> for(g in grps){
+   gname <- paste0("lb_wght",g)
+   math[, gname] <- ifelse(math$lb_wght == g, 1, 0) 
+   term <- paste("0", gname, paste0(gname,":grade"), sep="+")
+   re <- paste0("(", term, "|id)")
+   form <- paste(form, term, re, sep="+")
+ }
> 
> form <- as.formula(form)
> 
> m <- lmer(form, data = math)
> summary(m)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: math ~ 0 + 0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade + (0 + lb_wght0 + lb_wght0:grade |  
    id) + 0 + lb_wght1 + lb_wght1:grade + (0 + lb_wght1 + lb_wght1:grade |      id)
   Data: math

REML criterion at convergence: 15931.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.09189 -0.52867 -0.00063  0.53419  2.54169 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name           Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 id       lb_wght0       61.1969  7.8228        
          lb_wght0:grade  0.6711  0.8192   0.04 
 id.1     lb_wght1       97.4494  9.8716        
          lb_wght1:grade  1.4314  1.1964   -0.35
 Residual                36.2755  6.0229        
Number of obs: 2221, groups:  id, 932

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
lb_wght0        35.4848     0.3646   97.31
lb_wght1        32.8506     1.4214   23.11
lb_wght0:grade   4.2930     0.0902   47.60
grade:lb_wght1   4.8827     0.3414   14.30

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            lb_wg0 lb_wg1 lb_w0:
lb_wght1     0.000              
lb_wght0:gr -0.527  0.000       
grd:lb_wgh1  0.000 -0.567  0.000
```

Comment: Dear Livius, many thanks for taking the time to write this answer. I should say I already knew this answer, but was wondering if there might be a different coding alternative to either using `dummy()` or its exact mirror (what you kindly proposed). Ideas for such alternatives are, for example, reflected [**HERE**](https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer#different-level-3-variance-covariance-matrix). In any case, in the above case, I'm trying to fit what's called a *multiple-group analysis* . . .

Comment: . . ., In the current model, 2 different models are being estimated using the same call to `lmer()`. That is, a model for each level of `lb_wght`. A fully multiple-group analysis would be possible if we allow variances between each level of `lb_wght` to be different as well which is what we discussed [**HERE**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/508220/140365).

Comment: @rnorouzian Once again, you've got an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please ask questions about your actual problem and not about implementation details unless you want an answer to your implementation details.

Comment: Note also that "2 different models are being estimated...." is not true: a single model is being estimated (with corresponding partial pooling), but there is a particular blocking structure to the random-effects covariance matrix. I also have my doubts  that the generalized variant of this covariance structure is particularly useful -- why are you assuming that structure? What does that structure mean in real-world terms for your data when you have more than 2 groups? What is the inferential goal? What do your data represent?

Comment: Dear Livius, please refer to Chapter 6 of [This Book](https://www.guilford.com/books/Growth-Modeling/Grimm-Ram-Estabrook/9781462526062). If you can't access a copy of the book, I would be happy to send you one (via email). I'm studying the book right now for personal interest.

Comment: @rnorouzian In the question, the problem is explicitly stated as "binary predictor". That question has been answered. If you have a different question, then you should open a new question. Also, it is incumbent upon the person asking the question to put enough information in the question so that people can understand the question -- the person answering shouldn't have to look for information elsewhere. Finally, as it is now explicitly clear that this is `self-study`, questions on CrossValidated should include the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Dear Livius. I don't have a statistical question. I simply wanted to know if there is more smarter way to define the random-part of the syntax for example using one categorical variable (`lb_wght`) in the model. A purely R syntax question. However, since you "suspect the underlying statistical model is problematic", I prepared the chapter of the book in which this example is very clearly explained for your consideration [**HERE**](https://github.com/hkil/m/blob/master/G.pdf). You can just read pp. 115-123. Once again, many thanks for your insights.